# Changing the 3D Coordinate System in LibGDX

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

Currently in 3D coordinate systems point(0,0) starts from center. But I need it to be at top left corner. So how  to achieve it using perspective camera or any other way.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Why not just rotate the camera until (0, 0, 0) is in the upper left? Or are you trying to make it 2D instead of 3D?

Comment: Thanks @Steve Blackwell. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Steve Blackwell..

Moving camera to right at +x-axis and to bottom at -y-axis it shifted my view to top left corner.

Comment: This looks more like a response to Steve's comment, not an answer to your question.